# User Permissions in React Native for IOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, permissions

I want to use Internet in app and need to ask for permission for both IOS/Android. I  have checked out [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions) but could not set up the module because of the **react native link**  command. What is the easiest way to grant permissions in React-native? Any examples?

Comment: What version of react native are you using ? [Here's](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14812) a link that might help.

Comment: I am using **Verion 0.52.0** with Expo . I tried ejecting and linking. It linked but this time I couldn't use Expo. (I am not using Macbook btw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use internet by default if you use Expo (no need to ask internet permission). But if you want to ask the others permission check this link https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions.html

Example code :

```
async function getLocationAsync() {
  const { Location, Permissions } = Expo;
  const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
  if (status === 'granted') {
    return Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({enableHighAccuracy: true});
  } else {
    throw new Error('Location permission not granted');
  }
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thanks!